# How to access created pdf document on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift

My app has an action that creates pdf file. After creating file on simulator I can access the created file on Mac but on iPhone I can not. Even I have searched but couldn't find. On Acrobat Reader neither.

So what can I do with this created pdf file? Should I convert it ePub or something?

This is my code for creating pdf:

```
func createPdfFromView(_ imageView: UIImageView, saveToDocumentsWithFileName fileName: String)
{
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, imageView.bounds, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()

    let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    if (pdfContext == nil)
    {
        return
    }

    imageView.layer.render(in: pdfContext!)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()


}
@IBAction func createPdfAction(_ sender: UIButton) {

    createPdfFromView(ImageDisplay, saveToDocumentsWithFileName: "")
}
```

Comment: You can store the PDF to the Documents folder of the app. Setting `UIFileSharingEnabled` to YES will allow users to access the file(s) via iTunes.

Comment: How can I access created pdf file via iTunes? I tried but couldn't find. @frzi

Comment: @CactiApp where you want to access the file? from app it self or any other document view app?

Comment: @Jeyamahesan It's better if I can access on iBooks but If not any option is fine for me.

Comment: @CactiApp Please let me know given answer is working for you? is it satisfied your requirement?

Answer (score 1):

Write the PDF Data as a file in local path

```
private var pdfData: NSMutableData!
private var filPath: NSString!
private var docController: UIDocumentInteractionController!

func writeDataAsFile()
{
    //Search for local path
    let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
    let directoryPath = paths[0] as NSString

    //Appending file name to be saved in directory path
    filPath = directoryPath.appendingPathComponent("TestPDF.pdf") as NSString!

    //Check file is already exist in path
    let isFileExists = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: filPath as String)

    if(!isFileExists)
    {
        //pdfData is NSData/NSMutableData, Write to the filepath
        pdfData.write(toFile: filPath as String, atomically: true)
    }
}
```

`UIDocumentInteractionController` provides in-app support for managing user interactions with files in the local system

```
@IBAction func goPDF(sender: UIButton) {

    docController = UIDocumentInteractionController.init(url: NSURL.fileURL(withPath: filPath as String, isDirectory: true))
    docController.delegate = self
    docController.presentOpenInMenu(from: CGRect.zero, in: self.view, animated: true)
}
```

`UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` to handle document interactions

```
func documentInteractionController(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController, willBeginSendingToApplication application: String?) {
    print("willBeginSendingToApplication")
}

func documentInteractionController(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController, didEndSendingToApplication application: String?) {
    print("didEndSendingToApplication")
}

func documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu(_ controller: UIDocumentInteractionController) {
    print("documentInteractionControllerDidDismissOpenInMenu")
}
```

Using delegate in your ViewController should conforms the `UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate` like this, for example, in ViewController

```
import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate {
}
```

For open PDF in iBooks the menu will provide "**Import with iBooks**" option. This option will lead to open the PDF in iBooks after importing.

Comment: I'm new on iOS programming. Please bear with me. I see error on `docController.delegate = self`. Error is *Cannot assign value of type ViewController to type UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelagete?

Comment: declare that your class conforms the UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate. like this, class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UIDocumentInteractionControllerDelegate

Comment: I see this error now: Tread: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION(code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0). I'm trying on simulator.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the above code. it is working here. this error is due to your implementation. so please upload your sample on github. i'll look into that.

Comment: iBooks app is not available in simulator. so you cannot test it in simulator. test the above in device.